# ggplot formating in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I would like to as how to work with `ggplot` in `shiny`

When I was trying to write simple kmean app on build-in mtcars dataset I cannot plot result in ggplot.

Result can be ploted but plot seem to be bit  off.

I would like to ask for any advice:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(mtcars)),
    selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(mtcars),
                selected=names(mtcars)[[2]]),
    numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3,
                 min = 1, max = 9)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot1')
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
  selectedData <- reactive({
    mtcars[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
  })

  clusters <- reactive({
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    x <- input$xcol
    y <- input$ycol

    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x, y)) +
      geom_point(size = 4, aes(color = factor(clusters()$cluster)))
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: you might want `aes_string` instead of `aes` in ggplot since you are passing variable names from `input` as strings containing the names of variables

Comment: YEAP-  that solved the issue, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can we change this piece of work and try again?
This works for me!

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
x <- input$xcol
y <- input$ycol
ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x, y)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, aes_string(color = factor(clusters()$cluster)))  })
```

Comment: This approach is mutch better - since this approach also work on `shinyapps.io`